# Include a line break in algorithm-caption while maintaining indentation

Tags: captions, line-breaking, algorithms

I've a question about the alignment of the caption in an algorithm-environment. For instance, the following code-example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Text Text\newline Text}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State bla
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

produces
[image]

However, the third "Text" should be directly under the first "Text". How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `caption` package with a hanging indent style as follows:

[image: Sample output]

[image: Longer sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[algorithm]{format=hang,singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Text Text\newline Text}  
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State bla
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text\newline
More text}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State bla
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Why do you use singlelinecheck=false? This doesn't change anything in my captions.

Comment: Without `singlelinecheck=false` the first example with a short caption doesn't get a hanging indent after the `\newline`.

Comment: I, too, have tried with `format=hang` but I forgot about `singlelinecheck=false` :( +1. BTW: `hangindent=0pt` is superflous. :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller You are right about the `hangindent=0pt`; the internals of the caption set up styles do indeed set this to `0pt`, so it is unnecessary and I have now removed it from the code.  It would be nice if the documentation told us about the default value.

Answer (score 3):

Load the `caption` package and declare:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{custom}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}\vspace*{0pt}#1#2\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\linewidth}\vspace*{0pt}#3\end{minipage}%
}
```

After that,

```
\captionsetup[algorithm]{format=custom}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{custom}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}\vspace*{0pt}#1#2\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\linewidth}\vspace*{0pt}#3\end{minipage}%
}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{format=custom}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\newline Text on a new line}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State bla
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]